# Using both Firebase and Amplify in one React native App

Tags: firebase, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, firebase-analytics

There is a big debate on the internet about Firebase vs Amplify. Get that. What I dont get is why so little to noone actually considers using both, or nobody just writes about it. To me both have clear advantages in different fields:

- Firebase definitely seems to be handier when it comes to analytics and push notifications , AWS doesnt even offer ads as far I as know. And Pinpoint is quite confusing in its documentation.
- AWS Cognito make more sense to anyone using AWS Services for the backend.
- Firebase also offers all analytics and messaging for free regardless of the amount of data, whereas in AWS as usual you are hooked in right away with more AWS services. Firebase Storage is also more expensive than AWS once you have some significant traffic.

So I was thinking why not using Amplify SDK for Cognito and S3 whereas Firebase SDK takes care of analytics, Push Notifications and Ads. I dont see any disadvantages myself, but again - i have never built a mobile app, I am a pure backend developer. Can anyone come up with problems of this setup or just confirm it is absolutely fine?

Thanks!

ps. i am thinking of an app written in react native

Answer (score 0):

I'm early into very similar research, so take this information with a grain of salt.

Regarding push notifications, Amplify's documentation for Android includes either setting your app up in Firebase or using Pinpoint. This documentation can be found here:

[Amplify Push Notifications - Getting Started](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/push-notifications/getting-started/q/platform/js/)

This appears to be a direct tie to Firebase's push notification functionality, so I don't believe you'd get any of the other features Firebase offers with this implementation.

Regarding the other features, I believe your assessment is correct in that whichever deployment toolchain you choose to use you're subject to their analytics options.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on something similar and have always wondered why there isn’t more out there on this subject. Leveraging the best from both seems like the next step when looking to implement either.

Did you come across any issues?

I’m using Firebase SDK for Authentication, Auth, and Firestore (albeit will probably switch to S3 for storage). Amplify for everything else. NextJs frontend, no mobile.

Comment: Ive decided to go with Amplify for everything except for analytics and ads . Works for me. no issues